# Generate deb from dependent ros package locally

Tags: deb, ros-kinetic, bloom-release, dependencies, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is related to the question [#280235](https://answers.ros.org/question/280213/generate-deb-from-dependent-res-package-locally/#280235) where there's a dependency problem using bloom to generate a .deb file locally.
I've added the key to rosdep in order to solve that problem but now I've other problem.

After using bloom generate to create the debian files, I try to run fakeroot to create the binary .deb file and it fails as you can see in the bash file: [fakeroot bash](https://pastebin.com/suP5Z0bP)

```
$ fakeroot  debian/rules binary 
 ...
Project 'qt_ros_interface' tried to find library 'robis_math_utilities'.
The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you
compile project 'robis_math_utilities'? Did you find_package() it before
the subdirectory containing its code is included?
...
```

This library is one of the dependencies of my package that I've previously installed in `opt/ros/kinetic` (also available in catkin)

EDIT 1

Using `dpkg-buildpackage` as suggested by @nuclearsandwich gave me a similar problem:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package ros-kinetic-qt-ros-interface
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.0.0-0xenial
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution xenial
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by user <user@user.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source --before-build qt_ros_interface
dpkg-source: info: using options from qt_ros_interface/debian/source/options: --auto-commit 
dpkg-source: warning: can't parse dependency ros-kinetic-robis_math_utilities
dpkg-source: error: error occurred while parsing Build-Depends
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build qt_ros_interface gave error exit status 255
```

This package also depends on another package that was installed in using the same method, but only this library is giving me troubles..

EDIT 2

The issue with dpkg-buildpackage is solved, my rosdep file had `ros-kinetic-robis_math_utilities` instead of  `ros-kinetic-robis-math-utilities` but the original issue is not solved yet..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288410/generate-deb-from-dependent-ros-package-locally/) by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
The linked fakeroot bash file appears to be a mix of commands run and their output. If that's a separate bash script that you're using in your release process can you provide a link that is just the bash source?

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
Maybe I gave it the wrong name, that is just what appears in the terminal when I run the `fakeroot`

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
I see, thanks for clarifying. I'd suggest trying to build the package using the command in my answer below. I think it's the most expedient way to do so.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
`dpkg-source: warning: can't parse dependency ros-kinetic-robis_math_utilities`

Debian package names do not contain underscores. I expect your rosdep.yaml file might have some mistakes, can you post it please?

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
You're right, it was an error on rosdep that I corrected.   But now I've the exact same error I had when I used fakeroot,, heres the [log file](https://pastebin.com/x2MWfQsS)

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
Have you created the package for robis_math_utilities and installed it on your system? Since bloom sources only your /opt/ros/kinetic installation packages in the local workspace are not used.

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
Yes I've done that. I wrote it on the question

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
Sorry I missed it! Are you able to build qt_ros_interface in a workspace by itself with only /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash sourced?

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
I can't.. this [error](https://pastebin.com/4RQfG2V3) appears, but the package is there..

```
$roscd robis_math_utilities/
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robis_math_utilities$
```

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
That error suggests to me that robis_math_utilities is either not installed or there's something wrong with the package. What are the outputs of `apt list --installed ros-kinetic-robis-math-utilties` and `dpkg -L ros-kinetic-robis-math-utilities`?

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
You can see the outputs [here](https://pastebin.com/R46etV8N)

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
Looking at that output, I do not see any header or compiled library files in the robis-math-utilities package contents. Based on the CMakeLists.txt you posted below I would expect a library file and some headers.

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
I see that for this package there's no headers files in opt/ros/kinetic/include ... But that should have been created..

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
There's quite a few things that could be going on. I would suggest trying to build your robis_math_utilities package with the dpkg-buildpackage command then check it with `dpkg -c path/to/ros-kinetic-robis-math-utilities*.deb`to see if the new package contains the expected files.

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
I've built it with dpkg-buildpackage already..  i will do the check command later

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-16**:
@nuclearsandwich  i've done the `dpkg -c` commando and here is the [result](https://pastebin.com/DcPRZWrV) :

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-16**:
Again the library and header files are definitely missing. Someone with more catkin experience than myself might be able to tell why.

I'd propose editing the question (or creating a new one) to ask why your other package is missing files.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2019-01-23**:
@billyDong did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be possible to build the package by invoking commands from the debian rules file directly, but it is probably easier to use `dpkg-buildpackage` to build a package locally as long as your local system matches your target system.

If your package depends on any other custom packages, you will need to make sure that you build and install those packages first.

After running bloom you can create a local clone of the release repository to build your package.
The release repository has branches of the form `${packagetype}/${rosdistro}/${suite}/${package}`. For example, `debian/kinetic/xenial/qt_ros_interface` From a local checkout of this branch you can run the command `dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc`. This will build the binary package only (`-b`), and will not attempt to sign the changes file (`-uc`). This probably isn't what you want to be doing for your official release packages but it is suitable for quickly building debs.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
Thank's for your answer but I didn't understand the local check out part.. my package is on ~/catkin_ws/src/qt_ros_interface. And I have'nt mentioned but I'm using ubuntu 16.04

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
If you ran bloom-release, it would have a created a release repository. Usually  with a name like `package_name-release`. If you used git bloom-release instead you may have created the repository manually before doing so.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
The release repository is the repository created in Step 3 of http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease/#Creating_a_Release_Repository

That's the repository which contains your source along with the generated debian info from bloom.

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
I'm sorry, I still  don't understand.. I ran `bloom-generate` and not `bloom-release`. By running bllom-generate, do I have to make the code available on git hub (I already have a  git repository but I want to keep it private for now)?

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
Ah, that was my misunderstanding! Since you ran bloom generate, your current workspace should have a debian folder in it and you can run the dpkg-buildpackage command above from the package directory in your workspace.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-04-13**:
bloom-generate does not require a separate repository.

Release repositories do not need to be public, bloom's easy path expects that you're contributing packages upstream but it is not a requirement.

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-04-13**:
@nuclearsandwich could you please see the edit on the question. I've a similar problem with your approach.